# Translating long texts with html formatting

Tags: plugins, customization, translation

I was wondering what is the best way to translate some longer texts with html formatting. There was a couple of solutions I came across, but did not know what would be the best one.

- Writing a couple of html files with language extension (e.g. maintext_en.html, maintext_de.html, ...) and import this files.

  *Pro*: It's easy for me

  *Contra*: Not so easy for translators
- Writing only one html file with some markers and parse the file.

  *Pro*: A bit easier for translators, they have to edit only one file.

  *Contra*: I need a parser
- Using l10n inside the code

  *Pro*: The easiest way for translators

  *Contra*: Uses a lot of memory when the plugin runs. And the risk of losing some formattings.

What is the best and most efficient way to make long texts within a plugin translateable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most translation tools are really hard to use when you try to handle a long text, so the translators have to use a HTML editor anyway. Use separate files, but use the language prefix as directory name:

- en

  - main.html
  - help-main-options.html
  - help-special-options.html
- de

  - main.html
  - help-main-options.html
  - help-special-options.html

That’s easier to handle for translators and for you too.

You could also set up a WordPress site for translations and use a custom post type, so translators can use the regular editor ([outdated example](https://github.com/wpkrauts/Extended-Help)), and you handle just the import and export.

Answer (score 0):

Using gettext is the only proper way translations in WordPress, but it really depends on the context.

In my themes, for example, I always have a place in footer for some copyright text and whatnot. I can assume that this text will be changed by any user (even the English-speaking one), so using gettext in this context is a little bit pointless, as user would have to go through the entire process of translating the theme just for the footer text. For this purpose I use WordPress settings API and create an option page that lets users choose their own footer text.